# onchange is not triggred

Tags: jquery

I'm not able to trigger programmatically `onChange` event of a select tag.
http://jsfiddle.net/XqnLE/

did I miss something?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to include the JS in a different place in your fiddle (either head or body, not DOM load or ready): http://jsfiddle.net/XqnLE/1/

Comment: :) http://jsfiddle.net/5Qzpz/ see the left panel `no wrap` not `on load`

Comment: You guys just read my thoughts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TestIt` function is out of the scope, since in JSFiddle code inside JavaScript window usually is configured to be inside DOM ready handler.

It will work fine if you place it in the global scope:

```
<script>
    function TestIt() {
        $("#tt").trigger("change");
    }
</script>

<select id="tt" onchange="alert('onchange triggered!!')">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="trigger" onclick="TestIt();"/>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XqnLE/2/

---

It will also work if you set `no wrap` instead of `onLoad` when choosing the JQuery settings.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XqnLE/5/.